# PHP ignore case sensitivity when comparing array values

Tags: php

I have to modify some code in a application I am working on that is using the array_diff($array1,$array2) method. The problem I am having is it is case sensitive and I need to have it return the correct value if the array values match even if the case is different. I don't want to change the case to lowercase because I need the value returned to keep its case. I'm a little confused as the best method to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need: [array_udiff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) and [strcasecmp](https://www.php.net/strcasecmp)

```
$result = array_udiff($arr1, $arr2, 'strcasecmp');
```

E.g.

```
<?php
$arr1 = array("string","string","string");
$arr2 = array("String","string","sTRING");

$result = array_udiff($arr1, $arr2, 'strcasecmp'); 
print_r($result);
?>
```

`$result` should echo `array ( )`

Answer (score 0):

Use

`strcasecmp` — Binary safe case-insensitive string comparison

```
<?php
$var1 = "Hello";
$var2 = "hello";
if (strcasecmp($var1, $var2) == 0) {
    echo '$var1 is equal to $var2 in a case-insensitive string comparison';
}
?>
```

[Refer this link for more information](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)

Comment: This is comparing arrays, not strings.

Comment: see my example above for array comparing, using @pavun_cool's `strcasecmp` and `array_udiff`

Comment: not sure that works for my situation, I am comparing two arrays whatever values are not in both get returned and then those are used

Answer (score 0):

Serializing can help, so you can use strcasecmp on the resulting strings:

```
<?php

$arr1 = array("string","string");
$arr2 = array("String","sTRING");

$equal = (strcasecmp(serialize($arr1), serialize($arr2)) === 0);

?>
```